# Using javascript for loop, access php array variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, for-loop

A small problem that I can't seem to figure out;

So I have a php array in which I want to access through javascript using a for loop to specify the index. For example,

```
<?php 
 $myArray = array("a", "b", "c");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        $('<div class="pops"> Hello '+ THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE PHP VARIABLES +'</div>').appendTo(elements[i]);
</script>
```

I would like to access the variables in $myArray using the 'i' in the javascript for loop since there will be the same number of variables as for loop iterations.

I have tried to read up on possible solutions to solve this but have not been able to figure it out. 
I have tried using the following code but came up with nothing;

```
$('<div class="pops"> Hello '+ <?php echo $myArray[i]; ?> +'</div>').appendTo(elements[i]);
```

I feel like I am running into trouble here because of the following two reasons; My syntax is probably completely wrong. The 'i' variable I am using to access the index of the array is still a javascript variable.

I am new to javascript/php so please forgive me.
Thanks for any sort of help!

Answer (score 2):

Easy, convert to json and add to script element.

```
<?php $myArray = array("a", "b", "c"); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

// I assume phpArray length equals to elements length

var phpArray = <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?> ;
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    $('<div class="pops"> Hello '+ phpArray[i] +'</div>').appendTo(elements[i]);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually still getting an empty myArray on return

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of doing this: One is with JSON as @venca said.

The other way is using a php loop instead.

```
<?
  foreach ($myArray as $elem){
    echo '<div class="pops"> Hello '.$elem.'</div>';
  }
?>
```

This will generate one div with class pops for each element in your php array. If you want to run some javascript code instead, you should to something like this:

```
<script>
<?
  int i=0;
  foreach ($myArray as $elem){
    echo '$("<div class=\"pops\"> Hello '.$elem.'</div>").appendTo(elements['.i.'])';
    i++;
  }
?>
</script>
```